# Check, if row of matrix is full of 1s in O(1) time

Tags: c, function, matrix, time-complexity

I have an assignment, where I need to write in C a function, which checks, if there is a row in a given matrix that is full of '1's. The matrix values can be only '1's or '0's (boolean matrix).

For example: (size 3)

```
1 1 0  
1 1 1  
0 0 1
```

> returns 1 (true)

```
1 1 0  
1 0 1  
1 0 0
```

> returns 0 (false)

Now, it's really simple with no restrictions, but then I am asked to do this with time complexity of `O(1)` and I have no idea, where to start.

If it helps: We were asked to write 2 functions before this one:

1. `init(n, A)` fill n-size matrix A with '1's in `O(n^2)`
2. `flip(A, i ,j)` turns value at [i,j] from '0' to '1' or '1' to '0' in `O(1)`

Comment: Keep track of the number of 1s per row.

Comment: Or even simpler, keep track of rows without flipped values.

Comment: wouldn't it require a loop to count the 1s? it has to run with time complexity of O(1)

Comment: Set during init and "*keep track*" while flipping, then there is no need to count.

Comment: If the matrix size is constant then you can scan the entire thing in O(1) time.  If the matrix size can vary, then it can't be done in O(1) time unless you already have the result kept as part of your matrix data.

Comment: Assuming you have to check every element of the row, there is no way to get O(1) complexity.    However, the results of checking each row can be stored in an array - and retrieving values from that array will be O(1) - the complexity will be O(n) where n is average number of elements in the row.   There is, of course, the need to keep the array consistent with the rows (i.e. if the rows change, so does the corresponding element of the array).

Comment: @user8: Keeping track of the rows without flipped values does not work since an element can be flipped multiple times.

Comment: You have not stated the problem fully. It is impossible to compute in O(1) time whether a row of *n* elements is all ones. Therefore, a function to return an indication of whether a row is all ones cannot compute this from the array alone. It must have additional data. Likely you were given an assignment to design data and algorithms—emphasis here on keeping additional data, not just the array itself. As interjay notes, it is obvious what additional data solves the problem. But this is a good example of why you should explain the whole problem—a narrow focus misses the big picture.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It does work, but yes, it is not that straightforward. You have to track the number of flipped values, as with the ones.

Comment: @user8: So essentially you are saying to count the zeros (the number of elements flipped from the initial 1 and not flipped back). How is that simpler than counting the ones?

Comment: @EricPostpischil elsewhere, you asked for a Stack Overflow rule or guideline that says a person who knows an answer to a question should not answer the question until a MCVE is provided? [Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: That does not say not to answer questions without an MCVE. It suggests avoiding questions that are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem. But, if a person has understood the problem and has an answer, the question is sufficiently clear and detailed to be answered. The lack of an MCVE is then not a barrier.

Answer (score 2):

The catch is to have previously done the "accounting work" and now to just fetch the result in constant time.

There are different strategies that might be applied here. After you have initialized the matrix with 1s in `O(n^2)` time, now with each flip, you could either keep track of:

- the 1s
- the flips (or equivalently 0s)

If you choose to track 1s, then you need additional `O(n)` of memory to each matrix to store them. And when you flip a `1`, you subtract 1 from your *ones-on-a-row* array. When you flip a `0`, then you add 1 to your ones-on-a-row* array.

If you track flips, you do it by row, and you need again `O(n)` of additional memory. Similarly, you have a helper array, where you store the number of flips for each row. If you flip and the new is `0` - add one, if you flip & the new is `1` - subtract one.

Then, at your `O(1)`-function, you just check against the row's stored value at the respective array position.

Comment: By "track flips" you seem to essentially mean store the number of zeros in each row? "Track flips" sounds to me more like something that would increment to two if you flip the same element twice, which would not be useful.

Comment: You are right, it could be put *track 0s*, instead. Because there is just no 3rd possibility. But, no, you don't increment it twice. See the last but one paragraph of my answer. A matter of perspective...

Comment: @aschepler Thanks for the remark. I have edited my answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

O(1) (constant time) is not possible, except when the size of the matrix is fixed.
Then you can simply use some `if` operations for every row:

```
// Matrix has fixed size 2x2
if (matrix[0][0] && matrix[0][1]) return 1;
if (matrix[1][0] && matrix[1][1]) return 1;
return 0;
```

(What do you need the `flip` function for?)
Otherwise: Just iterate through the matrix:

**Init:**

```
void init(unsigned n, unsigned matrix[n][n]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      matrix[i][j] = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

**Option 1:**

```
unsigned check(unsigned n, unsigned matrix[n][n]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    unsigned found = 1;

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      if (!matrix[i][j]) {
        found = 0;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (found) {
      return 1;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
unsigned check(unsigned n, unsigned matrix[n][n]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    unsigned sum = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      sum += matrix[i][j];
    }

    if (sum == 3) {
      return 1;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

trade space for time:

`x`

`y`

`row[y]`: array of length y keeps track of 1 in the matrix in a specific row

`column[y]`: array of length x keeps track of 1 in the matrix in a specific column

`init(n, A)` fill n-size matrix A with '1's in O(n^2) and keeps track of `row` and `column` arrays

`flip(A, i ,j)` turns value at [i,j] from '0' to '1' or '1' to '0' in O(1), after each call of `flip` increment of decrement `row` and `column` arrays accordingly in the right index. After the last/every flip operation check the size of row[y]

Answer (score -2):

As the "Big O" notation wants give an *order* of time (complexity), it will only look at order 1, n, squares, logs etc.

Going through a `n x n` matrix takes n<sup>2</sup> steps (time), so is O(n<sup>2</sup>). `init` will be doing something like that.

O(1) should accomplish a task in one step. Flipping can do that as it goes to the element to flip in one step (indexing the array).

Note: the algorithms (functions) to accomplish init and flip are very simple, but I don't want to do your homework for you, just get you going.

Comment: already written 'init' and 'flip' with the necessary time complexity

Comment: O(1) means that the function has a set number of steps which would not be affected by the input correct?

Comment: There is no answer to the question in this. I understand you might want to encourage a student to think for themselves, but that is not what Stack Overflow answers are for.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, he says he has no idea where to start. Seems now he has, so it answers his question.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Stack Overflow is an enduring repository for questions and answers, not a record of individual help sessions.